# crystal report total

Tags: crystal-reports

suppose if i have many locations like L!,L2,L3 etc

each location hasAmount column with many records
how 
can i totl the amount of each location in Crystal report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a *Group for the Location*, and then add a total field for *SUM of Amount*.

If you need me to explan the steps for you, please feel free to ask.

- On the menu click *Report* and then
  *Group Expert*.
- A new window will pop up called
  *Group Expert* with 2 boxes (*Available Fields and Group By*) and
  buttons to move fields from left to
  right.
- Move the Location Field to the *Group
  By* box and click *OK*.
- Now you report should show a *Group
  Header 1* containing a field *Group

  ## 1 Name* and *Group Footer 1* which should be blank.
- Now on the menu click *Insert* and
  *Summary*. You should see a new window called *Insert Summary*.
- In the *Choose the field to
  Summarize*, change the field to the required Amount field to be summed.
- Change the Calculate this summary
  from *Maximum* to to *Sum*.
- Change the Summary Location from
  *Grand Total(Report Footer)* to *Group #1* and click *OK*.

That should be about it. Now you can play around with the formatting as required.